# Here.com map not rendering in v-for loop/ mapsjs-core.js:43 Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: H.Map (Argument #0 [object

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, here-api

stack: php/laravel/vue.js/postgres

I am making a get request to a backend that is displaying data in a table successfully.

In a separate div I have the here.com map rendering also successfully.

The ultimate goal is to take the lat and lng data from my table and display it as markers on the here.com api map within the v-for loop. So each row will have its own map with custom markers.

In the meantime, I just wanted to move the map, with hard coded coordinates, inside of the for loop so it would display on each row. When I move the div inside of the cell it gives this error:

```
mapsjs-core.js:43 Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: H.Map (Argument #0 [object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement])
    at new D (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:43:977)
    at new U (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:381:348)
    at VueComponent.mounted (http://localhost:8080/service/di_reports/geo_stop:280:24)
    at callHook (http://localhost:8080/js/vue2/vue.js:1830:19)
    at Object.insert (http://localhost:8080/js/vue2/vue.js:1999:5)
    at invokeInsertHook (http://localhost:8080/js/vue2/vue.js:4119:28)
    at Vue$3.patch [as __patch__] (http://localhost:8080/js/vue2/vue.js:4261:5)
    at Vue$3.Vue._update (http://localhost:8080/js/vue2/vue.js:1720:19)
    at Vue$3.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vue2/vue.js:1695:10)
    at Watcher.get (http://localhost:8080/js/vue2/vue.js:740:27)
```

Here's the main map code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Vue.component('test', {
        template: '#test-template',
        props: {
          apikey: String
        },
      
  data: function() {
        return{
            test: <?= json_encode($test) ?> ,
              stop_actual_latitude: <?= json_encode($test_actual_latitude) ?>,
              test_actual_longitude: <?= json_encode($test_actual_longitude) ?>,
              lat: <?= json_encode($lat) ?>,
              lng: <?= json_encode($lng) ?>,

            platform: {},
            map: {}
        }
      },
    created: function() {
            this.platform = new H.service.Platform({
              apikey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              
            })
          },
    mounted: function() {
            this.map = new H.Map(
                this.$refs.map,
                this.platform.createDefaultLayers().vector.normal.map,
                {
                    center: {lat: 33.753746, lng: -84.386330},
                    zoom: 12
                }
            );
            let mapEvent = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(this.map);
            let behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvent);
            this.dropMarker({ lat: 33.753746, lng: -84.386330});
            this.dropMarker({lat: 33.7748, lng:-84.2963})
            this.drawCircle({ lat: 33.753746, lng: -84.386330}, 8046.72);
            
    },
```

and finally the HTML

```
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Date</th>
          <th scope="col"> ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Exp Lat</th>
          <th scope="col">Exp Lng</th>
          <th scope="col">Act Lat</th>
          <th scope="col">Act Lng</th>
          <th>Map</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
        <tr v-for= "test in tests">
          
          <td>@{{stuff}}</td>
          <td>@{{stuff}}</td>
          <td>@{{stuff}}</td>
          <td>@{{sstuff}}</td>
          <td>@{{stuff}}</td>
          <td>@{{stuff}}</td>
          <td>   
 
          <div ref="map" id="map" >

          </div>
          </td>
         
        </tr>

      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: All your maps have the same `id`. The `id` attribute of any element in your markup has to be unique across the entire document. Note you can use the same `ref` across multiple elements in Vue but, when you do, `$refs[refName]` will be an array holding all of them, so you'll need to find the correct one (probably based on index). `console.log()` is your friend.

Comment: A simple workaround is to wrap the entire map functionality into a reusable component. (i'd name it `<here-map>`). You still need to use unique ids, if you do need ids. But each map component will have its own scope and you won't get any conflicts. In each row, you'd have a `<td><here-map v-bind="{ /* props you want to pass to it */ }" /></td>`.